# Qual a raiz morfológica para as letras [a] e [o] marcarem, respetivamente, os géneros feminino e masculino?

Tags: gênero, morfologia

Qual a raiz morfológica para o facto de as letras [a] e [o] marcarem, respetivamente e na generalidade, os géneros feminino e masculino dos artigos, substantivos e dos adjetivos?

Bem sei que há exceções como `problema`, `sofisma` ou `tribo`, mas são de facto exceções. Tal declinação para definir o género gramatical, tem origem no Latim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A terminação *-a* para o feminino e *-o* para o masculino já vêm do latim. Inicialmente, no latim clássico, não eram marcadores de género, mas foi essa função que acabaram por adquirir, quer no português, como no castelhano e no italiano; no italiano, apenas no singular. Esta evolução do latim para as modernas línguas românicas vem explicada nesta [*Comparative Grammar of the Romance Languages* (Nativlang.com, 2017)](http://www.nativlang.com/romance-languages/grammar/nouns-number.php?e=0,1), e mais sumariamente na *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, volume I, p. 53-4).

No latim clássico os substantivos eram declinados—tinham a terminação modificada—segundo os casos, a que correspondiam diferentes funções sintáticas. Por exemplo a palavra *rosa* tinha, entre singular e plural, sete formas diferentes; e só tinha sete porque alguns casos têm formas iguais [(Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rosa#Latin):

```
               Nominativo    Genitivo    Dativo     Acusativo     Ablativo    Vocativo
Singular:         rosa       rosae        rosae       rosam         rosā        rosa
Plural:           rosae      rosārum      rosīs       rosās         rosīs       rosae
```

Este modelo de declinação—chamado “primeira declinação” [(*First Declension*, Wikipedia)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_first_declension)—é um de cinco que existiam para os substantivo no latim. Os substantivos que seguiam este modelo eram na sua maioria femininos. Na evolução do latim para quase todas as modernas línguas românicas perderam-se os casos. Nas línguas românicas ibéricas foi o acusativo que sobreviveu (*rosam* no singular, *rosās* no plural); o *m* final do singular perdeu-se no latim vulgar, e daí ficarmos com *rosa* e *rosas*. No italiano foi o nominativo que sobreviveu, e daí eles terem *rosa* no singular e *rose* no plural. O [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_first_declension) lista algumas exceções masculinas desta declinação que continuam masculinas e terminadas em *-a* em português: *escriba, poeta, pirata*. Substantivos masculinos acabados em *-ma*, como *sistema, sintoma, clima, drama*, são geralmente de origem grega.

A nossa terminação *-o* do masculino vem da segunda declinação [(*Second Declension*, Wikipedia)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_second_declension), de que é exemplo *mūrus* (“muro, parede”; [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/murus#Latin)):

```
               Nominativo    Genitivo    Dativo     Acusativo     Ablativo    Vocativo
Singular:         mūrus      mūrī         mūrō        mūrum         mūrō        mūre
Plural:           mūrī       mūrōrum      mūrīs       mūrōs         mūrīs       mūrī
```

Os substantivo que seguiam este modelo de declinação eram quase todos masculinos e neutros. No evoluir para as línguas modernas o neutro passou a masculino. Nesta declinação as terminações do acusativo eram *-um* no singular e *-os* no plural. O *m* final do singular perdeu-se no latim vulgar, de que resultaram as terminações *-o* e *os* do português e castelhano. No nominativo, donde vem o italiano, as terminações eram *-us* no singular e *-ī* no plural. Daí ser *muros* em português e castelhano, mas *muri* em italiano.

Portanto a princípio *-am, -as* e *-um, -ōs* eram apenas algumas das terminações possíveis da mesma palavra. Depois, segundo a *Gramática do Português* (p. 52), “no final da latinidade”, ao mesmo tempo que desapareceram os diferentes casos, “a alternância entre declinações passou a ser vista como um recurso sempre disponível para expressar a diferença de género”.

Comment: excelente resposta, muito obrigado prezado @Jacinto

Answer (score 6):

Como sabe, os substantivos no latim tinham cinco *declinações*, que são como as conjugações do verbo, e eram distinguidas por uma vogal temática:

1. a primeira declinação, com tema em **a**, continha nomes principalmente femininos, mas alguns masculinos como *nauta* "marujo" e *agricola* "agricultor" (geralmente nomes de profissões ou empréstimos do grego);
2. a segunda declinação, com tema em **o** (no período clássico, esse **o** se passou a escrever "u" nos casos nominativo e acusativo, mas o tema é "o"), continha nomes principalmente masculinos e neutros, mas alguns femininos, como *fagus* "faia" e *prunus* "ameixeira" (geralmente, nomes de árvores ou de cidades gregas);
3. a terceira declinação, com tema em **i** ou em consoante, continha nomes de vários gêneros indistintamente;
4. a quarta declinação, com tema em **u**, continha poucos nomes, em sua maioria masculinos; e
5. a quinta declinação, com tema em **e**, continha pouquíssimos nomes, a vasta maioria feminina.

Já na era clássica, havia uma tendência de a quarta e a quinta declinação desaparecerem, absorvidas na segunda e na primeira, respectivamente. Sobraram então três declinações no latim da Idade das Trevas: uma com nomes principalmente femininos e terminada com **a**, uma com nomes principalmente masculinos e terminada com **o**, e uma com nomes de todos os tipos e terminada com **i** (posteriormente transformado em **e**) ou consoante.

Além disso, há também a questão dos adjetivos. Como sabe, os adjetivos não têm gêneros, mas devem concordar com os substantivos que modificam, e portanto devem ter uma forma para cada gênero. Então pode-se analisar como se formavam estas diferentes formas dos adjetivos, que eram formados por trocas de sufixos.

Os adjetivos em latim caíam em duas classes: na primeira, as formas masculinas e neutras terminavam com **us** e **um**, respectivamente, e as femininas terminavam em **a**: por exemplo, o adjetivo *bonus* (m) *bona* (f) *bonum* (n). Na segunda, as formas masculinas e femininas todas terminavam com **e** ou **i**: por exemplo, o adjetivo *fortis* (m) *fortis* (f) *forte* (n). Portanto, nos adjetivos, também, temos a mesma situação que nos substantivos: formas masculinas terminadas em **o**, formas femininas terminadas em **a**, e outras formas que não terminam em nenhuma das duas, mas que frequentemente não mudam de forma do masculino para o feminino.

Como se pode ver, conforme o latim evoluiu para o português, acabamos tendo classes de palavras com tema em **o** e em **a** que eram majoritariamente masculinas e femininas, e uma classe de palavras que não terminavam nem em uma, nem em outra, mas que não tinham grande tendência para qualquer um dos gêneros.

Por isso, e graças a algum nivelamento analógico (por exemplo, as árvores passaram a ter nomes terminados em **a** de modo que *fagus* virou *fagea* virou "faia"), os fonemas **o** e **a** *no fim dos substantivos* acabaram se tornando marcadores de gênero nas línguas latinas que não perderam-nas, como o português, o espanhol e o italiano.

Comment: Exactamente o que significa "terminada em <a/o/i/u/e>"? Por que *prunus* é "terminada em o" e não "u"?

Answer (score 2):

Na maioria das línguas indo-europeias -a final num radical indica feminino, por vezes -e também (vide 5ª declinação no latim clássico que passou toda para 2ª no latim tardio die - dia, ou a tendência no Português para reconhecer palavras terminadas em -e como feminino ao contrário das restantes neo-latinas ex: ponte, fonte). As restantes distribuem-se entre masculino e neutro. Sendo que em Português não existe neutro, todas as palavras neutras em latim passaram para masculino. As línguas indo-eurpopeias modernas têm evoluido no sentido de eliminar o neutro e simplificar o género associado a palavras que não têm género natural "cão" vs. "cadela".