# Origem do termo grosseiro para "flatulência"

Tags: etimologia, origem

Por que *flatulência* tem um termo pejorativo chamado *peidar*?

De onde surgiu esta expressão?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Na verdade *peido* é a palavra mais antiga, vindo já do latim *peditum* [(vê *peido* no Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/peido), que já tinha o mesmo significado [(vê *peditum* no Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peditum#Latin). *Flatulência* vem do francês *flatulence* [(Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/flatul%C3%AAncia), que vem de *flatulent* [(CNTRL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/flatulence), que por sua vez vem também do latim, *flatus* [(CNTRL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/flatulent); mas *flatus* siginificava em latim apenas ‘sopro, respiração, brisa’ [(Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flatus#Latin); só no século XIX, ou talvez mesmo no XX é que *flatulência* e *flato* aparecem como alternativas polidas a *peido*.

Dos fenómenos conhecidos na evolução do português é de esperar que *peditum* tenha perdido o *m* ainda no latim vulgar [(ver esta resposta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/qual-a-raiz-morfol%C3%B3gica-para-as-letras-a-e-o-marcarem-respetivamente-os-g%C3%A9/4440#4440); na evolução para o português tenha perdido o *d* intervocálico, dando lugar primeiro ao hiato, [pe.i], e depois ao ditongo [pei] (comparar com latim *credere* > português antigo *creer* (com hiato) > português atual *crer*); e o *t* passou a *d* (comparar com latim *totus, rota* > português *todo, roda*).

*Peido* aparece já no século XIII em cantigas de escárnio e maldizer. [Nesta cantiga de Pero Garcia Burgalês](http://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?ling=eng&cdcant=1415&nl=17&tr=1&pv=sim) encontramos “pois m’eu tanto por vós de peidos vazo” (‘pois eu por vós tanto de peidos me vazo’). [Nesta outra de Fernão Garcia Esgaravunha](http://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=1543&pv=sim) temos “estornudou [‘espirrou’] três peidos” e “feriu [‘disparou’] três peidos”; também se encontra nesta cantiga “peeu” (‘peidou’); *peeu* é uma forma do antigo verbo *peer*, que vem do latim [*pedere* (wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedo#Latin), que significava ‘peidar’. Em espanhol ainda é *peer* [(RAE)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SKJCAgH). [*Peidar* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/peidar) formou-se já no português a partir de *peido*.

Comment: Tive o cuidado em não fazer uma pergunta muito longa para não dar um ar de zombaria com a palavra. Que bom que a resposta foi muito polida e com contexto histórico. Achei muito interessante.

Comment: @LCarvalho, a pergunta está bem. Poderias ter alongado se precisasses. Toda a palavra, mesmo que inapropriada em certos ambientes, faz parte da língua e tem uma história que vale a pena conhecer. Acrescentei um parágrafo sobre a porvável (mais que provável) evolução.